# This is a delete method by ID, returning a TodoDataService, now I want to filter a todo item to delete

Tags: javascript, angular-cli, angular2-services

I'm creating an Angular C.L.I small project, that adds and removes To-do items from a list. In this delete method below, what filter method does in this context?

```
deleteTodoByID(id: number):TodoDataService {
    this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !==id);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Your code should be provided as text and not image. Have you looked at the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) creates a new array of all the elements that 'pass' the filter (and return a truthy value). So in this example, the filter will produce a new array with any elements where the ID of the element **isn't** equal to the ID given to the function. `this.todos` is then set equal to this new array.

This has the effect of removing any objects within the array where the `id` is equal to the `id` given to the function `deleteTodoByID`.

Comment: Thank you @varbrad i got it